# Dynamics CRM Deserialize nested FormXml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-parsing, crm

I need to deserialize nested FormXml file using by C#. The problem is I don't have an idea how to create a class which contain all of I needed nested elements and attributes.

The FormXml is below: (I make xml simpler)

```
<form >
 <tabs>
   <tab name="tab_1" ... >
     <labels>
        <label description="Tab1" languagecode="1049" />
     </labels>
     <columns>
        <column width="100%">
          <sections>
            <section name="ACCOUNT_INFORMATION" .. >
                <labels>
                    <label description="About" languagecode="1049" />
                </labels>
                <rows>
                    <row>
                      <cell id="{}">
                        <labels>
                          <label description="Phone" languagecode="1049" />
                        </labels>
                        <control id="telephone1"/>
                      </cell>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                      <!--same -->
                    </row>
                </rows>
            </section>
            <section name="COMPANY_PROFILE" .. >

            </section>
          </sections>
        </column>
     </columns>
   </tab>
   <tab name="tab_2" ... >
    <!--same -->
   </tab>
 </tabs>
</form>
```

I need take `<section>` array, in `<section>` `<labels>` and `<rows>`:

In `<labels>` take the `<label>` attribute `< .. descrition = "..">`

In `<rows>` take the `<row>` -> `<cell>` -> `<control id>`

I create the class XmlParser:

```
 public class SectionRoot
    {
        [XmlArray("section", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [XmlArrayItem("labels", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public Section[] Sections { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("label")]
    public class Section
    {
        [XmlAttribute("description")]
        public string SectionName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("row")]
    public class Row
    {
        [XmlElement("cell")]
        public Control Cell { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("control")]
    public class Control
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
    }
```

But I'm confused.. How can I make the true XmlParser class?

Answer (score 1):

You could use xsd.exe tool for this. First, create an xsd schema from your xml code. Save your xml in a file called form.xml

```
xsd.exe form.xml
```

Now, create a class from the generated schema:

```
xsd.exe form.xsd /c
```

This is the output I got.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Este código fue generado por una herramienta.
//     Versión de runtime:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Los cambios en este archivo podrían causar un comportamiento incorrecto y se perderán si
//     se vuelve a generar el código.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// Este código fuente fue generado automáticamente por xsd, Versión=4.6.1055.0.
// 


/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class labels {

    private labelsLabel[] labelField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("label", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public labelsLabel[] label {
        get {
            return this.labelField;
        }
        set {
            this.labelField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class labelsLabel {

    private string descriptionField;

    private string languagecodeField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string description {
        get {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string languagecode {
        get {
            return this.languagecodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.languagecodeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class form {

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("labels", typeof(labels))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("tabs", typeof(formTabs), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class formTabs {

    private formTabsTab[] tabField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("tab", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public formTabsTab[] tab {
        get {
            return this.tabField;
        }
        set {
            this.tabField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class formTabsTab {

    private labelsLabel[][] labelsField;

    private formTabsTabColumnsColumn[][] columnsField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("label", typeof(labelsLabel), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public labelsLabel[][] labels {
        get {
            return this.labelsField;
        }
        set {
            this.labelsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("column", typeof(formTabsTabColumnsColumn), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public formTabsTabColumnsColumn[][] columns {
        get {
            return this.columnsField;
        }
        set {
            this.columnsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class formTabsTabColumnsColumn {

    private formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSection[][] sectionsField;

    private string widthField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("section", typeof(formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSection), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSection[][] sections {
        get {
            return this.sectionsField;
        }
        set {
            this.sectionsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string width {
        get {
            return this.widthField;
        }
        set {
            this.widthField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSection {

    private labelsLabel[][] labelsField;

    private formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCell[][][] rowsField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("label", typeof(labelsLabel), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public labelsLabel[][] labels {
        get {
            return this.labelsField;
        }
        set {
            this.labelsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("row", typeof(formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCell[]), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("cell", typeof(formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCell), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false, NestingLevel=1)]
    public formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCell[][][] rows {
        get {
            return this.rowsField;
        }
        set {
            this.rowsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCell {

    private labelsLabel[][] labelsField;

    private formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCellControl[] controlField;

    private string idField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("label", typeof(labelsLabel), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public labelsLabel[][] labels {
        get {
            return this.labelsField;
        }
        set {
            this.labelsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("control", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCellControl[] control {
        get {
            return this.controlField;
        }
        set {
            this.controlField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class formTabsTabColumnsColumnSectionsSectionRowsRowCellControl {

    private string idField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working for small xml, but not working in my case.(  After creating .cs file from .xsd and running the program, i took a lot of errors(